# log4j inside and outside of a tomcat webapp

Tags: spring, log4j, tomcat7

I have a webapp set up to log over slf4j and log4j. The webapp is configured with Spring.

The relevant web.xml stuff is on the bottom. The problem I've got is that I also want to use this webapp inside of an application that launches tomcat itself via the embedded API. Everything is find until the webapp shuts down, and then I get.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger    (org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Is there some way to make the 'inside the webapp' stuff play nicely with the outside stuff?

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/spring-app-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
   <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
   <param-value>bt.r4dws.root</param-value>
</context-param>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger in web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266139/log4jwarn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger-in-web-xml)

Comment: @Ralph no I am not missing that line from my log4j.properties, and log4j works fine until the webapp shuts down.