# Why are log4j messages not showing in the console?

Tags: java, spring, debugging, model-view-controller, log4j

I am using logj4 in a spring mvc application.
I am working on in my logs on a tomcat 6 server and I am getting the following messages:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

in the stdout files on the tom cat server. I want to be able to see messages while i access methods and objects. This is how i am using log4j:

```
class ...

private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass()); 

logger.info("My message here");
```

For some reason i am not seeing any messages in my logs and i am seeing the above warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you have not set up logging for your application properly yet.

Try looking at the first few results of a [Google search for you error](https://www.google.com/search?q=log4j:WARN+No+appenders+could+be+found+for+logger+(org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).+log4j:WARN+Please+initialize+the+log4j+system+properly.) Particularly questions [about setting up web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266139/log4jwarn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger-in-web-xml).

Comment: This works for my stdout but why am i not seeing my custom messages in my code showing up in any of the logs?

Comment: ok sorry i am now seeing them just alot of information came up my messages are in between