# No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j

I have put log4j to my buildpath, but I get the following message when I run my application:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (dao.hsqlmanager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

What do these warnings mean?  Whats the appender here?

Comment: That seems to be a runtime warning. Are you sure you see this when you compile?

Comment: Did you try visiting the URL in the last line of the warnings?

Comment: yes!!! but it doesn`t say much... I found out that I need a property file to configure my appender!

Comment: Manually edit configuration files to add the appender. Make  sure you have the right & valid configuration document.

Comment: See also the question [log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger in web.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266139/log4jwarn-no-appenders-could-be-found-for-logger-in-web-xml)

Answer (score 580, accepted):

This [Short introduction to log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) guide is a little bit old but still valid.

That guide will give you some information about how to use loggers and appenders.

---

Just to get you going you have two simple approaches you can take.

First one is to just add this line to your main method:

```java
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Second approach is to add this standard `log4j.properties` (taken from the above mentioned guide) file to your classpath:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Comment: Just first step is ok. Quote from Short introduction to log4j guide

Comment: For new stumble upons... add log4j.properties file to src/main/resources and that is assuming you have a maven project. Stuff in src/main/resources are included on the classpath.

Comment: In IntelliJ idea open module setting and select your resource folder and click resources, it will automatically add your every resource to the classpath.

Comment: Didn't help.  I use Eclipse Neon for C++, and I've put the log4j.properties alongside the eclipse executable and didn't help

Comment: `log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1` is the line I was missing all the time.

Comment: The first step, real did the trick. Appreciate for this answer.

Comment: `BasicConfigurator.configure();` is magical

Answer (score 83):

It looks like you need to add the location of your `log4j.properties` file to the Classpath in Eclipse.

Make sure your project is open in Eclipse, then click on the "Run" menu at the top of Eclipse and click on the following:

1. Run
2. Run Configurations
3. Classpath (tab)
4. User Entries
5. Advanced (button on the right)
6. Add Folders
7. then navigate to the folder that contains your log4j.properties file
8. Apply
9. Run

The error message should no longer appear.

Comment: Warning messages are not appearing now but still the logs are not written at desired location

Answer (score 63):

Quick solution:

1. add code to **main function**:

   ```
   String log4jConfPath = "/path/to/log4j.properties";
   PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
   ```
2. create a file named log4j.properties at **/path/to**

   ```
   log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
   log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
   ```

Comment: Place the log4j.properties file inside resource directory like 
src/test/resource

Comment: To avoid explicit declaration of the log4j.properties path; place it within your project folder and access it like 

    String log4jConfPath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+File.separator+"log4j.properties";

Answer (score 42):

This is just a warning.

#### Fixing

This occurs when the default configuration files `log4j.properties` and `log4j.xml` can not be found and the application performs no explicit configuration.

To fix that, simply create/copy `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` into your a location on the *classpath* (usually the same as the jar files).

Optionally set java option: `-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///path/to/log4j.properties`.

> `log4j` uses `Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource()` to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check the file system. Knowing the appropriate location to place `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` requires understanding the search strategy of the class loader in use. `log4j` does not provide a default configuration since output to the console or to the file system may be prohibited in some environments.

#### Debugging

For debugging, you may try to use `-Dlog4j.debug=true` parameter.

#### Configuration of `log4j.properties`

Sample configuration of `log4j.properties`:

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Print only messages of level WARN or above in the package com.foo.
log4j.logger.com.foo=WARN
```

Here is another configuration file that uses multiple appenders:

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=example.log

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
```

#### Apache Solr

If using *Solr*, copy `<solr>/example/resources/log4j.properties` into a location on the *classpath*.

Sample configuration of `log4j.properties` from Solr goes like:

```
#  Logging level
solr.log=logs/
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, CONSOLE

log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x \u2013 %m%n

#- size rotation with log cleanup.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=4MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=9

#- File to log to and log format
log4j.appender.file.File=${solr.log}/solr.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p - %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}; %C; %m\n

log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop=WARN

# set to INFO to enable infostream log messages
log4j.logger.org.apache.solr.update.LoggingInfoStream=OFF
```

---

See also:

- [Short introduction to log4j: Default Initialization Procedure](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html#defaultInit)
- [Why can't log4j find my properties in a J2EE or WAR application?](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#a3.5)

Answer (score 24):

Most of the answers here suggested that `log4j.properties` file be placed in the right location(for maven project, it should be located in `src/main/resources`)

But for me, the problem is that my `log4j.properties` is not correctly configured. Here's a sample that works for me, you can try it out first.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: The fact that log4j considers "cannot find file" and "incomplete spec in file" to be the same error is a time waster.

Comment: For me, this is the best answer. I vote up and I have added some explanations in your answer.

Comment: `src/main/resources` seems to be the right directory for the `log4j.properties` file while using Maven, but I am not sure if this is true for non-Maven projects too.

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had the file in the right place etc, but something was messed up in the log4j.properties file. Copying in the example from this answer made it come to life for me

Answer (score 9):

As explained earlier there are 2 approaches

First one is to just add this line to your main method:

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

Second approach is to add this standard **log4j.properties** file to your classpath:

While taking second approach you need to make sure you initialize the file properly,
Eg.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("log4j property file path"));
props.setProperty("log4j.appender.File.File", "Folder where you want to store log files/" + "File Name");
```

Make sure you create required folder to store log files.

Comment: I was having same problem and I used BasicConfigurator.configure(); in main method and now code is executing properly.

Answer (score 9):

First of all: Create a log4j.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Place it in src/main/resources/

After that, use this 2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

It is necessary to add this final dependency to POM file:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 7):

You use the `Logger` in your code to log a message. The `Appender` is a Object appended to a `Logger` to write the message to a specific target. There are `FileAppender` to write to text-files or the `ConsoleAppender` to write to the Console. You need to show your code of the Logger and Appender setup for more help.

please read the [tutorial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) for a better understanding of the interaction of Logger and Appender.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure the properties file has properly set.
And again, it seems like that the compiler cannot find the properties file, you can set as follow at the pom  (only when you use maven project).

```
<build>
       <sourceDirectory> src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
       <testSourceDirectory> src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
             <resource>
                  <directory>resources</directory>
             </resource>
        </resources>           
</build >
```

Comment: This! I spent hours to find an answer. My case code works well in Linux but have this error in windows (same NB IDE) and all above solutions not work!

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue when I tried to run the JUnit test class.

The issue is resolved after I manually added the log4j.properties file in the src/test/resources folder.

Adding the below code to the log4j.properties file solved the issue:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, stdout

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 6):

I get the same error. Here the problem which leads to this error message:

I create some objects which use the Logger before I configure the log4j:

```
Logger.getLogger(Lang.class.getName()).debug("Loading language: " + filename);
```

Solution: 
Configure the log4j at the beginning in the main method:

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure(xmlLog4JConfigFile); 
// or BasicConfigurator.configure(); if you dont have a config file
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Everybody's just assuming Spring or Tomcat, or whatever to initialize the configuration.

Answer (score 6):

I think you should understand where the log4j jar file or the Java code looks for the log4j configuration files.

`src/main/resources/log4j.properties` is Eclipse path.
Place them in a proper location so that you don't have to hard code the absolute path  in code.

Read my article and sample solution for that
https://askyourquestions.info/how-to-see-where-the-log-is-logger-in-slf4j/

Answer (score 6):

Add the following as the first code:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("log4j.rootLogger", "WARN");
PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the error was the flag "**additivity**". If it's "false" for you root project package, then the child packages will not have an appender and you will see the "**appender not found**" error.

Answer (score 3):

Another reason this may happen (in RCP4) is that you are using multiple logging frameworks in your target file.  As an example, this will occur if you use a combination of slf4j, log4j and ch.qos.logback.slf4j in your target files content tab.

Answer (score 2):

Log4J display this warning message when Log4j Java code is searching to create a first log line in your program.

At this moment, Log4j make 2 things

1. it search to find `log4j.properties` file
2. it search to instantiate the appender define in `log4j.properties`

If `log4J` doesn't find `log4j.properties` file or if appender declared in `log4j.rootlogger` are not defined elsewhere in `log4j.properties` file the warning message is displayed.

CAUTION: the content of Properties file must be correct.

The following content is NOT correct

```
log4j.rootLogger=file

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=c:/Trace/MsgStackLogging.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
```

because `file` appender is declared in LOWER-CASE in `log4j.rootlogger` statement and defined in log4j.appender statement using UPPER-CASE !

A correct file would be

```
log4j.rootLogger=FILE

log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=c:/Trace/MsgStackLogging.log
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%m%n
log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=false
```

If MAVEN is used, you must put log4j.properties files in `src/main/resources` AND start a MAVEN build.

Log4j.properties file is then copied in `target/classes` folder.

Log4J use the `log4j.properties` file that it found in `target/classes` !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Eclipse and this problem appeared out of nowhere after everything worked fine beforehand, try going to `Project - Clean - Clean`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the reason was apparently different, and the error message misleading.

With just this in my build.gradle, it would complain that slf4j was missing at the beginning of the log, but still log things, albeit in a poor format:

```
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```

Adding that dependency would cause the discussed "no appenders could be found" error message for me, even though I had defined them in `src/main/java/log4j.properties`:

```
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25'
```

Finally, adding the following dependency (which I only guessed at by copycatting it from another project) resolved the issue:

```
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.25'
    compile 'commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2'
```

I don't know why, but with this it works.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when trying to build an executable jar with maven in intellij 12. It turned out that because the  java manifest file didn't include a class path the log4j properties file couldn't be found at the root level (where the jar file was executed from.)

FYI I was getting the logger like this:

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MyClassIWantedToLogFrom.class);
```

And I was able to get it to work with a pom file that included this:

```
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> 
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.mainPackage.mainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>.</Class-Path> <!-- need to add current directory to classpath properties files can be found -->
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your project is open in Eclipse, then click on the "Run" menu at the top of Eclipse and click on the following:

1. Run
2. Run Configurations
3. Classpath (tab)
4. User Entries
5. add jar on the right
6. add log4j jar file
7. Apply
8. Run

The error message should no longer appear.

Answer (score 1):

The reason can be lack of the word `static` in some:

```
final static Logger logging = Logger.getLogger(ProcessorTest.class);
```

If I make logger the instance field, I am getting exactly this very warning:

```
No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.kafka.producer.Sender)
```

What is worse, the warning points not to `ProcessorTest`, where the mistake lives, but to an absolutely different class (Sender) as a source of problems. *That* class has correct set logger and need not any changes! We could look for the problem for ages!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem when I use log4j2. My problem is caused by using wrong dependent library:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Instead, I should use:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In my case, I have a log4j2.xml defined in my "resources" directory, and specified to use it by:

```
System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "log4j2.xml");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.
I just forgot to mark the resources directory in IntelliJ IDEA

1. Rightclick on your directory
2. Mark directory as
3. Resources root

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error message in IntelliJ when trying to run unit tests. I had both Eclipse and IntelliJ open at the same time, which may have caused this problem. After I closed both IDE's and ran a maven command line build the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

My Eclipse installation could not find `log4j.properties` when running *JUnit* tests from Eclipse, even though the file was located at `src/test/resources`.

The reason was that Eclipse (or the *m2e* connector) did not copy content from `src/test/resources` to the expected output folder `target/test-classes` - the root cause was that in the project's properties under *Java Build Path* -> *Source* tab -> *Source folders on build path* -> *src/test/resources*, somehow there was an `Excluded: **` entry. I removed that *excluded* entry.

Alternatively, I could have manually copied `src/test/resources/log4j.properties` to `target/test-classes/log4j.properties`.

Answer (score 0):

If `log4j.properties` is indeed on the classpath, you are using Spring Boot to make a WAR file for deployment to an app server, you are omitting a `web.xml` file in favour of Spring Boot's autoconfigure, and you are not getting any log messages whatsoever, you need to explicitly configure Log4j. Assuming you are using Log4j 1.2.x:

```
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // Launch the application
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run( AppConfig.class, args );
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( SpringApplicationBuilder application ) {
        InputStream log4j = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("log4j.properties");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4j);
        return application;
    }

// Other beans as required...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add the relevent project contains log4j in java build path, I add mahout_h2o into it when I met this problem in  a mahout project using eclipse, it works!

Answer (score 0):

if you work together with a lot of projects you may face a style problem.

*you have to have one lof4j.properties file and this file is included log properties of other project.

*Beside you can try to put log4j properties files into src path when the project is worked Linux OS, libs of other project and log4.properties files can be under one folder into a location on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

First import:

```
 import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
```

Then add below code to main method:

```
String log4jConfPath ="path to/log4j.properties";
PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
```

Create a file at **path to**  and add the below code to that file.

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{2}: %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution on this site worked for me https://crunchify.com/java-how-to-configure-log4j-logger-property-correctly/. I now see no warnings at all from log4j

I put this in a log4j.properties file that I put in src/main/resources

```
# This sets the global logging level and specifies the appenders
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, theConsoleAppender

# settings for the console appender
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.theConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the log4j JVM argument **Dlog4j.configuration**

**In general:**

Add the JVM argument that points out the log4j config file.
The syntax is just like follows:

```
java [ options ] -jar file.jar [ arguments ]
```

A sample of a real command line is just like the following:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=conf/log4j.xml -jar myJarFile.jar myArg1 myArg2
```

**For IntelliJ IDE users:**

```
1.Run/Debug Configurations
2.Edit configurations...
3.VM options
4.Enter the same value also starting with "-D"
```

**Tips:**

1.Eclipse IDE users will find an equivalent approach

2.For the run/debug configuration editor, it's very likely that, at the beginning of the times, your particular executable file is not there. Depending on the size of the project you're currently working on, it can be unpleasant to navigate directories to find it. It's less of a hassle if you just *run/execute the file (click play) once before proceeding to run/debug config* no matter what the execution result is.

3.Pay attention to your working directory, relative paths, and classpath.

Answer (score -4):

In java eclipse copy your conf_ref to conf folder.