# Java Eclipse and jasper report: how to locate log4j.properties?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, log4j

I always get an error about this

`log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlDigesterFactory).`
`log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.`

i dont know where is that log4j.properties is. is it downloadable? becouse i currently have zip pack named
jasperreports-4.7.0,there are so many library there,but which one of it? please help me.
i have no luck finding it in google.
i have method that shows the table of my database

`pubic void btnIreport(){`

```
try{
    JasperDesign jd = JRXmlLoader.load("C:\\Users\\Nickz08\\Desktop\\test.jrpxml");
    String sql = "select * from tblStudentAccount order by name";
    JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
    newQuery.setText(sql);
    jd.setQuery(newQuery);
    JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, null,conn);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jp);

}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();

}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the following link how to create a log4j.properties file ([No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j))

you can add it any where you want, when you run your project, configure the classpath and add the location of the log4j.properties files by clicking on: Run->Run Configuration -> [classpath tab] -> click on user Entries -> Advanced -> Select Add Folder -> select the location of your log4j.properties file

and then -> OK -> run

and it should get loaded

Comment: how to insert it in line of code? like this `PropertyConfigurator.configure("C:\Users\Nickz08\Desktop\log4j-1.2.15");`

Comment: @user3053928, you can set it using System.setProperty(), but it has to be set before the first call to any logging method (which is usually pretty hard to achieve).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create log4j.properties file in your src folder it might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be in your classpath. Check for it over there.