# Can not understand the warning thrown on running selenium script

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Whenever I ran my webdriver script in eclipse, using java, I got following warning:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

When I looked into Referenced Libraries I saw a 'log4j-1.2.14.jar'. This must have come along with default selenium download. What's its use??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log4j configuration is missing. Log4j scans for configuration files log4j.xml or log4j.properties on the classpath and cannot find either.

For details, have a look at [No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j) .

Example:
To setup a console appender, create file log4j.properties with the following contents and put it on the classpath:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %c - %m%n
```