# Not able to get the score logs for all possible solution using optaplanner in grails app

Tags: grails, logging, drools, optaplanner

Not able to get the score related logs in a problem solved by optaplanner getting the score logs in Java Application.

Also made changes in Config.groovy for logging but still not able to get the logs.

Here is the code snippet for config file.

```
// log4j configuration
log4j = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    debug      'grails.app.controllers',
               'grails.app.services',
               'grails.app.domain',
               'grails.app.tests',
               'grails.app.controller',
               'grails.app.utils'

    warn      'grails.app.controllers',
               'grails.app.services',
               'grails.app.domain',
               'grails.app.tests',
               'grails.app.controller',
               'grails.app.utils'       

   info      'grails.app.controllers',
               'grails.app.services',
               'grails.app.domain',
               'grails.app.tests',
               'grails.app.controller',
               'grails.app.utils'

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `debug`, add `'org.optaplanner'`.

If that doesn't just do it, also make sure that slf4j-log4j.jar is on  your classpath. See OptaPlanner docs chapter about logging and Slf4J docs.

Comment: Doesn't work. This jar is already available in classpath as it is already in grails dependancy.

Comment: Problem solved using this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j