# log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger. Log4j 1.2.17 jar

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am getting this error

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.company.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

This is my Main

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("This is debug");
        }

        //logs an error message with parameter
        logger.error("This is error");
    }
}
```

While this is my log.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout                             = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target                      = System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout                      = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern    = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file                               = org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File                          = C:\\log4j-application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize                   = 5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex                = 10
log4j.appender.file.layout                        = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern      = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and this is my file structure.

[image]

I am in learning stage of Log4J and trying to implement a dummy project to understand it deeply.

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add your `ressources` directory to your classpath. After that it should work.

Comment: Done. wasn't expecting it to be this much easy.

Comment: New to java. How to do that exactly?