# Unable to locate appender

Tags: java, logging, configuration, slf4j, log4j2

I am trying to migrate from `log4j 1` to `log4j 2` in a spring web application. When I build it I get the following error:

```
2015-08-10 16:26:36,222 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=AppenderRef] OK from factory method.
2015-08-10 16:26:36,222 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-08-10 16:26:36,222 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-08-10 16:26:36,223 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=root, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger]. Searching for factory method...
2015-08-10 16:26:36,223 DEBUG Found factory method [createLogger]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger.createLogger(java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.Level,java.lang.String,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderRef[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Property[],org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration,org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Filter).
2015-08-10 16:26:36,224 DEBUG Calling createLogger on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig$RootLogger for element Root with params(name="null", name="INFO", name="null", ={appFileAppender}, ={}, Configuration(/Applications/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml), null)
2015-08-10 16:26:36,225 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=root] OK from factory method.
2015-08-10 16:26:36,225 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin]. Searching for builder factory method...
2015-08-10 16:26:36,227 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2015-08-10 16:26:36,228 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=loggers, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin]. Searching for factory method...
2015-08-10 16:26:36,228 DEBUG Found factory method [createLoggers]: public static org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Loggers org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin.createLoggers(org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig[]).
2015-08-10 16:26:36,229 DEBUG Calling createLoggers on class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggersPlugin for element Loggers with params(={app, analyticsLogger, dpLogger, trackingPixelLogger, filteredLogsLogger, trackingOffersPurchasingLogger, ifbLogger, trackingOffersUdidLogger, trackingOffersHeadersLogger, apLogger, s3AdminLogger, bookPackLogger, accumulatorLogger, appDownloadLogger, botDetectionLogger, fourGLogger, urlShortenerLogger, TrackingAllLogger, otiHeadersLogger, postpaidErrorTrackingLogger, root})
2015-08-10 16:26:36,230 DEBUG Built Plugin[name=loggers] OK from factory method.
2015-08-10 16:26:36,235 ERROR Unable to locate appender appFileAppender for logger
2015-08-10 16:26:36,237 ERROR No appender named fourGFileAppender was configured
```

Following jars are added to classpath:

1. log4j-slf4j-impl-2.3.jar
2. log4j-core-2.3.jar
3. log4j-api-2.3.jar
4. slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
5. commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
6. apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar

And my `log4j2.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">

    <Appenders>

        <RollingFile name="appFileAppender" fileName="/tmp/portal-fe.log"
                     filePattern="/tmp/portal-fe.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%p] | [%t] [%X{requestId}] [%X{x_msisdn}] [%X{x_rat}] [%X{x_forwarded_for}] [%X{circle}] [%C{1}:%L] %m%n"/>
        </RollingFile>


        <RollingFile name="analyticsFileAppender" fileName="/tmp/ops_bc_log"
                     datePattern="'-'yyyyMMdd">
            <PatternLayout
                    pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <Async name="ASYNC">
            <AppenderRef ref="appFileAppender"/>
        </Async>

        <Async name="ASYNC_2">
            <AppenderRef ref="analyticsFileAppender"/>
        </Async>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="app" level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="analyticsLogger" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="ASYNC_2"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="appFileAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j)

Comment: I checked the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j) but mine is different. I have properly added my log4j2.xml in the classpath and it is available in `/WEB-INF/classes/`. I guess I have configured the `log4j2.xml` incorrectly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your RollingFile configuration needs to specify what triggers a rollover. You do this by adding a `<Policy>` element. See the [RollingFile manual entry](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RollingFileAppender) for details.

I believe adding this snippet before the closing `</RollingFile>` tag should fix the issue:

```
<Policies>
  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</Policies>
```

For the analyticsFileAppender RollingFile appender you configured a `datePattern` where you meant to say `filePattern`. Below is the fixed config snippet.

```
<RollingFile name="analyticsFileAppender" fileName="/tmp/ops_bc_log"
             filePattern="'-'yyyyMMdd">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %m%n"/>
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
  </Policies>
</RollingFile>
```

Comment: I added `Policies` and `filePattern` like [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/38bbfc3dfc4861907e8e). Is it correct ?

Comment: Did it fix the problem?

Comment: It is giving me this [error](https://gist.github.com/ramswaroop/78eaac3e311863f605e3).

Comment: Config looks correct. I don't actually see any error, it looks like your app exits immediately. Can you try a simpler config first? Looks like you have 20 or so async appenders set up. Can you try with just one or two RollingFileAppenders first, make that work, then gradually add

Comment: I removed all loggers from [log4j2.xml](https://gist.github.com/ramswaroop/aab62f86d53b97f19c5d) except first one and here is the [error log](https://gist.github.com/ramswaroop/e4625610cb051cd25f8c).

Comment: Your config looks okay. You could simplify further by removing the named logger and make the root logger level DEBUG and point its AppenderRef to the ASYNC appender. However, I don't think that's the problem. What does your application do? It doesn't exit immediately, does it? Does your portal-fe.log file show anything?

Comment: See [Portal-fe.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/987f51bd921572cb6508), I guess the problem lies here.

Comment: One more thing, along with the 4 jars mentioned in the question, I also have `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar` and `apache-log4j-extras-1.1.jar` in my classpath. Is it okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86618/discussion-between-antara-roy-and-remko-popma).

Comment: Extras is for log4j-1.2, not Log4j2. You can try adding the log4j-1.2-api bridge that is part of log4j2. This routes all log4j-1.2 calls to log4j2.

Answer (score 0):

First, remove the Async appender, and point the appender-ref of the AsyncLogger to the ProcessorLoggingFile directly. Second, you must add includeLocation="true" on the AsyncLogger.

Having an async appender in addition to an async logger does not help and in this case might be what prevents the includeLocation from working correctly.

**EDIT:**
[CHECK THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j) question for more help.

Comment: Where did you place your log4j.xml. This problem might be occurred if you haven't added in the class-path. So placed log4j.xml or log4j.properties file in class path (/WEB-INF/classes/). 

i.e , WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml

Comment: I am getting this error too: `ERROR RollingFile contains an invalid element or attribute "datePattern"`. How do I specify the rollover strategy then? I guess through `filePattern` ?

Comment: Please refer this for date Patterns 'http://www.codejava.net/coding/configure-log4j-for-creating-daily-rolling-log-files'