# Log4 appender not found

Tags: java, logging, ant, log4j, apache-axis

I am making AXIS2 webservices and in that I have used Log4j. when running application it is giving error

```
 [java] log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.deployment.FileSystemConfigurator).
 log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

I have done following things

1. I have changed commons-logging property to use log4j ( as AXIS is using common logging )
2. To check if log4j.properties is in class path i have used resource bundle nad tried to a property from log4j.properties - which printed

Directory structure of my myapp.aar file is as below
[image]

**How do I go forward from here, I am clueless please help me.**

As suggested I run my app with -Dlog4j.debug=true  but where can I find log4j log

```
Execute:Java13CommandLauncher: Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
'-classpath'
'D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-launcher.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-antlr.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-apache-bcel.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-apache-bsf.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-apache-log4j.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-apache-oro.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-apache-regexp.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-apache-resolver.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-apache-xalan2.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-commons-logging.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-commons-net.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-jai.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-javamail.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-jdepend.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-jmf.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-jsch.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-junit.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-junit4.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-netrexx.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-swing.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant-testutil.jar;D:\Trikon\SCA Certification\SCA SAP Certification\Software\apache-ant-1.9.7\lib\ant.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib\tools.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\activation-1.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\antlr-2.7.7.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axiom-api-1.2.10.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axiom-dom-1.2.10.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axiom-impl-1.2.10.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-adb-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-adb-codegen-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-ant-plugin-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-clustering-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-codegen-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-corba-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-fastinfoset-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-java2wsdl-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-jaxbri-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-jaxws-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-jibx-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-json-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-kernel-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-metadata-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-mtompolicy-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-saaj-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-soapmonitor-servlet-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-spring-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-transport-http-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-transport-local-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\axis2-xmlbeans-1.5.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\bcel-5.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\commons-codec-1.3.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\commons-fileupload-1.2.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\commons-io-1.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\geronimo-jta_1.1_spec-1.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\geronimo-saaj_1.3_spec-1.0.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec-1.0.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\httpcore-4.0.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jalopy-1.5rc3.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jaxb-api-2.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jaxb-impl-2.1.7.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jaxb-xjc-2.1.7.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jaxen-1.1.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jettison-1.0-RC2.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jibx-bind-1.2.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\jibx-run-1.2.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\juli-6.0.16.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\mail-1.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\mex-1.5.4-impl.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\neethi-2.0.4.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\regexp-1.2.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\tribes-6.0.16.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\woden-api-1.0M8.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\woden-impl-dom-1.0M8.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\xalan-2.7.0.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\xml-resolver-1.2.jar;C:\axis2-1.5.4-bin\lib\xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar'
'org.apache.axis2.transport.http.SimpleHTTPServer'
'-Dlog4j.debug=true'
'./build/repo'
'-p15000'
'-Dlog4j.debug=true'
```

Comment: put your log properties to Java classpath

Comment: possible duplicate at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j

Comment: I am not able to see log4j logs with parameters,

Comment: @YeWin :  Could you please help me

Comment: I mean set your log properties files to Java classpath

Comment: @YeWin if you see image , you can see log4j property is in root directory where my source is. so it is in class path right?

Comment: no you have to had in Java classpath

Answer (score 0):

There are another option to define the location of log4j configuration file in Axis 2 web service , is by using **HttpServlet** which excite at application startup and define the location of file to log4j . The require code listed below :

1.Define you **servlet** in web.xml

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>log4j-init</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.log.LogInit</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>app-log4j-file</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/conf/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

in this example the location of log4j.properties file is under WEB-INF->conf

1.Create **LogInit** class extends **HttpServlet** under com.log package

```
public class LogInit extends HttpServlet{
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public void init() {
    String path =  getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    String fileName = getInitParameter("app-log4j-file");
    String strPathFile = path + fileName;
    if(strPathFile != null) {
      PropertyConfigurator.configure(strPathFile);
   }
}
}
```