# Maven webapp log4j missing property

Tags: java, maven, logging, log4j

There is a `maven` web app module, and I try to use `log4j` in order to log it.
This is what my project structure looks like:

[image]

So I think my property file is where it should be.

This is what my property file looks like:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %M %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/Users/me/front.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %M %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

This is how I init my `Logger`:

```
final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FragmentHandlerMB.class);
```

However, it doesn't work. I got this error message:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.kebodev.managed.FragmentHandlerMB).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Where should I put the property file? Thank you! 
The `log4j.properties` file in my classpath, I think this 
[No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j) is not the same issue.

After I create `mvn install` this is how my target looks like:

[image]

So i think, I have my `log4j.prperties` in runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j)

Comment: i Think it is not the same issue. I have my log4j.properties in the right place i think.

Comment: how are you running your java app?