# How to resolve 'Initialize the log4j system properly' error?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I've created a maven project and under `src -> test -> java`, I created package `learnlog4j` and under that package, I've test classes.

I've created `log4j.properties` under root of the project, which has following content -

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} %p [%C{1}] %m%n
```

But when I run following test class,

```
public class Log4jExample1 {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Log4jExample1.class);

    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(){
        logger.info("IN Before Class");
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
        logger.info("IN Test");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){
        logger.info("IN After Class");
    }
}
```

it gives error -

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (learnlog4j.Log4jExample1).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I searched over stackoverflow but that did not help. Could you please tell me if `log4j.properties` is at correct location? Or let me know if something that needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cann add a

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

in beforeClass()-Method to get a basic Console adapter.

To use your log4j.properties, use

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

See [No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j) for details.

Comment: THis does not read information from `log4j.properties` file. It logs as per default settings.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Sorry. I was mislead by the fact that your log4j.properties have configured a console adapter. I have updated my answer above.