# No appenders could be found for logger (com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig)

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, hikaricp

So I have been trying to configure the logger for HikariCP the entire weekend so far and now I am seeking help.
I cant exactly list what I already tried because I went through like everything I could find but here are two of the most promising things I have found so far.

The first thing would be this Stackoverflow Thread:
[No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j/12532442)
Which got marked as correct but when I add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom.xlm I still get the same error message.

The second thing I found was to just use

```
BasicConfigurator.configure();
```

While this DOES WORK it also enables logging for other libarys I have in my real Project which spam more log messages than I can handle so this is not an option.
This line of code was found on [No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j/12532442) which also states that using this configuration will work

```
# Set root logger level to DEBUG and its only appender to A1.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, A1

# A1 is set to be a ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# A1 uses PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

However after translating this piece to a XLM configuration I still got the exact same error message.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Here is my current log4j2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%logger{1}] - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig" level="debug" additivity="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is my current pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dinhware</groupId>
    <artifactId>StackOverFlowTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

So what am I doing wrong here, am I just missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that something was not correctly updating.
After I recreated my pom.xml file
I once again removed the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

and replaced it with the first one from my original post

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

which now does seem to work.