# Deployed jar in web sphere giving log4j properties file error

Tags: java, websphere-8, log4j

I have deployed the jar in web sphere application server. But it is giving me error.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger(com.ezmcom.ezmdb.temenos.integration.util.props.EzProps).

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

Can someone suggest me what is the issue.
I have log4j.properties file in my class path

Comment: are you sure it can find your log4j.properties file when you deployed?

Comment: @Ehcnalb I m not sure but in the server logs I can see that log4j.properties file is read by the server. And one more thing my log4j.properties file is in META-INF folder after building it into jar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j  may help you.