# Why do I get log4j warning in java with jasper report?

Tags: log4j, jasper-reports

I am using java jasperreport in java every time i compile it says

> log4j: warning no appender s could be found in logger , please
>   initialize logger system properly.

Answer (score 0):

## It's not a problem, don't worry about it.

Jasper reports library uses [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) as a logger, the warning you are seeing is that you have not configured it, but this reflects only on logging, the library works just fine.

If you don't care about jasper-reports log, don't worry about it.

If instead you like to see the log, debug the library etc. checkout  [log4j's manual](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) on how to configure it or see [No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j)