# How to configure Log4j2 properties where there are many log4j2.properties in an application

Tags: java, log4j2

I have an application with a number of supporting JARs that also have logging (log4j2.properties) files in them. Do I need to code entries in the main JAR's log4j.properties for all the different loggers in the different JARs in the main log4j.properties file, or does each log4j.properties file handle the code in that particular JAR?  How do I handle the log4j.properties in the supporting JARs?

This is the error I get where a company common jar is throwing this error. I don't know what to do.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.mycompany.common.properties.AbstractPropertyReader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

This application turns into a runnable JAR.

I found lots of examples of log4j.properties config, but I can't find one that addresses this. That's probably because it's so simple only I am the one who can't see it.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j Did you check the accepted answer in this already.

Comment: did you read the link shown on the warning?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No appenders could be found for logger(log4j)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12532339/no-appenders-could-be-found-for-loggerlog4j)

Comment: Log4j 1.x and Log4j 2.x are mostly incompatible. Log4j 1.x uses `log4j.properties` as one of the configuration files, while the `log4j2.properties` files are used by Log4j 2.x. BTW: a library should **not** depend on `log4j-core` (just `log4j-api`) and should not provide `log4j2.properties` files.

Comment: Thank you, and that is great advice.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, does this mean I should remove log4j-core from my pom?

Comment: From the library sub-projects, yes. Add it to the application as `runtime` dependency.